# removing all sub strings of a string in C

Tags: c, string, substring

Ive been trying to remove all occurrences of a substring from a given string but my code has a bug which I don't know how to resolve. When two substrings are back-to-back my code can only remove one of them.

This is my code:

```
void removeSub(char *str, char *sub, char *new) {
    int len = strlen(sub);
    char *subp = strstr(str, sub);
    int position = subp - str;
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++) {
        if (i >= position && i < position + len) {
            continue;
        }

        if (i == position + len - 1) {
            // update position
            subp = strstr(str + i - 1, sub);
            position = subp - str;
        }
        
        char ch = str[i];
        strncat(new, &ch, 1);
    }
}
```

a quick explanation of code: I copy the string char by char into another string(new) and whenever I see the substring along the way my code continues the loop and does nothing. when a substring is passed I relocate the next substring. (I know this isn't very efficient but I'm new and don't know many ways and functions)

Comment: Did you run the code in a debugger, tracing the code step by step inspecting the variables' values? If not then consider doing so. This helps.

Comment: What happens when `sub` not in `str`?

Comment: You have an extra semicolon after `if (i == position+len-1);`, which means the `if` has an "empty" statement and that the following block in `{}`s will be executed unconditionally.

Comment: @MOehm when I copied the code here I deleted a comment which was a part of code and this happened, that's not the issue

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it just copies the whole string into new

Comment: Well, just saying. But I think `(i == position+len-1)` cannot be true, because you have continued earlier. If `i == position + len - 1`, then `i < position + len` is also true.

Comment: In removing substrings from your string, consider the substring `"harm"`, do you want to remove `"harm"` if it appears as a single word, and in `"harmful"` where it is a lesser included string of another word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues:

- the loop `for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)` is very inefficient as the length of `str` is recomputed at each iteration of the loop. You should simply write:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
  ```
- when you skip the matched substring, the character after it is copied and `i` is incremented in the loop so the next occurrence is not tested correctly.
- the code to append a single character is inefficient: instead of `strncat(new, &ch, 1);` you should have a pointer to the end of the destination string and write `*p++ = str[i];` and set the null terminator after the end of the loop.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <string.h>
// remove all occurrences of sub in str into destination buffer new
// return a pointer to the destination string
char *removeSub(cont char *str, const char *sub, char *new) {
    char *p = new;
    size_t len = strlen(sub);
    if (len > 0) {
        const char *subp;
        while ((subp = strstr(str, sub)) != NULL) {
            memcpy(p, str, sub - str);
            p += sub - str;
            str = sub + len;
        }
    }
    strcpy(p, str);
    return new;
}
```

And an alternative without library calls:

```
// remove all occurrences of sub in str into destination buffer new
// return a pointer to the destination string
char *removeSub(cont char *str, const char *sub, char *new) {
    char *p = new;
    while (*str) {
        if (*str == *sub) {  /* potential substring match */
            for (size_t i = 1;; i++) {
                if (sub[i] == '\0') {  /* substring match */
                    str += i;
                    break;
                }
                if (str[i] != sub[i]) {
                    *p++ = *str++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            *p++ = *str++;
        }
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return new;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the loop keeps advancing. When you remove a substring, you need to subtract one from the loop index `i` so you search the same position again.

Comment: Note this was once the accepted answer until a better came along. I had noted the error, tried to put in a small correction, discovered on pulling the string I was going to rewrite the algorithm, decided that OP would be benefitted more by doing it himself. Had he not commented I would not delete it.